# Why does the broadcast timeout still occur, although we set the threshold very low?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Configuration：

```
Spark version: 3.1.2
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled = true
spark.sql.adaptive.enabled = true
spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold = 10MB
spark.sql.broadcastTimeout = 300
...
```

Code:

```sql
SELECT /*+ MERGE(a, b) */ a.memberId, b.name, a.amount
FROM trade AS a
JOIN member AS b ON a.memberId = b.id
WHERE b.isTrueMember = true;
```

At first, we don't use the join hint `/*+ MERGE(a, b) */`. The size of `trade` less than 10MB, then BroadcastHashJoin will be selected, this is correct and in line with expectations.

```
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Project [memberId#9554, name#9630, amount#9532]
   +- BroadcastHashJoin [memberId#9554], [id#9589], Inner, BuildLeft, false
      :- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[1, string, false]),false), [id=#34501]
      :  +- Filter isnotnull(memberId#9554)
      :     +- FileScan parquet xxx.trade[amount#9532,memberId#9554] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(memberId#9554)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[xxx://xxx;xxx;xxx/..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(memberId)], ReadSchema: struct
      +- Project [id#9589, name#9630]
         +- Filter ((isnotnull(isTrueMember#9608) AND (isTrueMember#9608 = true)) AND isnotnull(id#9589))
            +- FileScan parquet xxx.member[id#9589,isTrueMember#9608,name#9630] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(isTrueMember#9608), (isTrueMember#9608 = true), isnotnull(id#9589)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[xxx://xxx;xxx;xxx/..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(isTrueMember), EqualTo(isTrueMember,true), IsNotNull(id)], ReadSchema: struct
```

In my workflow, there are many table codes that will be executed after this section of SQL, but if this section of SQL reports an error, the following tasks will not be executed.

The current phenomenon is that sometimes this code will report a broadcast timeout error, but sometimes it will not. It is very unstable, stability is very important in our system, so I added `/*+ MERGE(a, b) */` hint in order to avoid BroadcastHashJoin.

**My questions：**

- Is BroadcastHashJoin also unstable due to network's instability?
- 10MB looks very small, Why does the broadcast timeout still occur sometimes?

If you need more information, please leave a message in the comment area.

More info:

```
cluster manager: Kubernetes
cluster located: Aliyun
data located: The data will be cached in Alluxio and asynchronously synchronized to Aliyun OSS

driver and executor config：
    spark.driver.memory: 4g
    spark.driver.memoryOverhead: 4g
    spark.executor.cores: 6
    spark.executor.memory: 23g
    spark.executor.memoryOverhead: 5g
    spark.executor.instances: 2

trade data is just one parquet file in Alluxio, no partitions, and size is 3.2MB.

We use the auto scaling feature of Kubernetes, which generally takes 2-3 minutes to take effect.
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would like to know: 1. Which cluster manager are you using? YARN or Kubernetes or cloud serverless environment (e.g. AWS glue) or others?  2. Where is your cluster and data located? Both on cloud or on premise? 3. What's the resource of your driver and executors? 4. How did you partition your `trade` data? Is it a lot of small chunk of data? Thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan Lam I added more information at the end, Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you also add the error stack trace you're getting?

Comment: @Koedlt Since I added the hint of `/*+MERGE (a, b) */`, the join strategy has become the SortMergeJoin, which will no longer report errors. I'm sorry I didn't keep the stack trace. Error log just like `Could not execute broadcast in 300 secs. You can increase the timeout for broadcasts via spark.sql.broadcastTimeout or disable broadcast join by setting spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold to -1`.

Comment: The reason can be that you have many executors, so it takes time to send the broadcasted table to all of the executors. I would increase the timeout of the broadcast as suggested in the error.

Comment: @Bibzon I have a new direction to solve this problem. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Might be related to [this.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-33933)

Essentially, there's an issue in Spark 3.0 with the adaptive query execution engine where the map and broadcast are being submitted at the same time and the map takes all of the resources, slowing down the broadcast. This isn't resolved until Spark 3.2 and it looks like you're running 3.1. I had a similar issue with a few jobs.

Assuming this is the issue, there are a few things you can do:

1. Upgrade to Spark 3.2 (might not be realistic)
2. Increase the broadcast timeout, perhaps significantly if the code is straightforward and you're sure it's just this section with the broadcast join. If you do this and it stabilizes while being faster than the merge join version, then it's probably just from this issue.
3. Disable `spark.sql.adaptive.enabled` so Spark isn't using the newer AQE - this is also a great test to see if this is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer which let me have a new direction to solve this problem. You deserve the 50 reputation! I will do a full test on the third step and then accept you answer.

Comment: @GuoranYun Thanks, hope that helps! I do have another suggestion that's not necessarily related so I didn't include it in the answer and maybe you already know - usually due to jvm limitations on file i/o it's best to keep the executor core count to 5 and under. You might see a small improvement to change it to 3 4 core executors instead of 2 6 core executors with the corresponding memory allocation changes